# Where can I find JSTL version 1.2.3 or newer?

Tags: maven, jstl

I am using jstl-1.1.2 jar in my application. Veracode shows high vulnerability for using this tag library. Veracode shows vulnerability for versions until 1.2.3. During my research I could only find version 1.2. Is there a version 1.2.3 for this jar? Or is there anything I can do to remediate this vulnerability?

What are my options? Please suggest.

My Maven dependency looks like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: *"Or is there anything I can do to remediate this vulnerability?"* Just don't use the JSTL `<x:parse>` and `<x:transform>` tags. These two are the only JSTL tags with the vulrenability. They are however very rarely used because the entire `<x:xxx>` and `<sql:xxx>` taglibs are since JSP 2.0 (in 2003) officially discouraged for production applications and recommended for prototyping only.

Answer (score 4):

Maven repository shows v.1.2 is available (Jun 23, 2011):

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, JSTL was moved to another place, v.1.2 (May 14, 2015)

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Similarly, Maven repository shows [v.`1.2.5` for taglibs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5) is available:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

So, only the taglibs can be updated to v.1.2.5 to mitigate [this vulnerability](https://snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JAVA-JSTL-30453):

> *Affected versions of this package are vulnerable to XML External Entity (XXE) Injection. Apache Standard Taglibs before 1.2.3 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or conduct external XML entity (XXE) attacks via a crafted XSLT extension in a <x:parse> or <x:transform> JSTL XML tag.*

Comment: 1.2 still has the vulnerability. The version which is acceptable is 1.2.3

Comment: Only taglibs have been updated, the latest version is 1.2.5 I mentioned above.  [Snyk report for taglibs](https://snyk.io/vuln/maven:org.apache.taglibs%3Ataglibs-standard-impl).  Update for JSTL is not available: [SNYK report on JSTL](https://snyk.io/vuln/maven:jstl:jstl)

Comment: Thanks Alex Rudenko!!I have updated the taglibs version to 1.2.3 which works fine. My only concern is for Jstl now.

Comment: The fix seems to be available only for the taglibs.